# Parsing unsigned integer from JSON dictionary in Swift

Tags: json, swift, int, unsigned-integer

I'm trying to write code to parse a JSON value (which could be a String or an Integer in the JSON) to an **optional unsigned integer** (i.e. `UInt?`), being tolerant to the value being missing or not being parsable - I only want the result to have a value if the source data contains a legitimate positive value:

```
convenience init(jsonDictionary: NSDictionary) {
    ...
    var numLikesUnsigned: UInt?
    if let likesObj: AnyObject = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("likeCount") {
        let likes = "\(likesObj)"
        if let numLikesSigned = likes.toInt() {
            numLikesUnsigned = UInt(numLikesSigned)
        }
    }
    self.init(numLikesUnsigned)
}
```

This seems incredibly unwieldy. Is it really this hard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply do like this:

```
var numLikesUnsigned = (jsonDictionary["likeCount"]?.integerValue).map { UInt($0) }
```

---

Since `NSString` and `NSNumber` both has `integerValue` property, we can access `.integerValue` no matter which type is that.

```
let dict:NSDictionary = ["foo":42 , "bar":"42"]

let foo = dict["foo"]?.integerValue // -> 42 as Int?
let bar = dict["bar"]?.integerValue // -> 42 as Int?
```

And, `Optional` has `.map` method:

```
/// If `self == nil`, returns `nil`.  Otherwise, returns `f(self!)`.
func map<U>(f: (T) -> U) -> U?
```

You can:

```
let intVal:Int? = 42
let uintVal = intVal.map { UInt($0) } // 42 as UInt?
```

instead of:

```
let intVal:Int? = 42

let uintVal:UInt?
if let iVal = intVal {
    uintVal = UInt(iVal)
}
```